# Add edges to a directed acyclic graph without introducing a cycle and/or new vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

Consider we have a directed `Graph G = (V, E)`.
Assume `|V| ≥ 5.`
Is it possible to add `|V|` directed edges to `G` without introducing a cycle (and without introducing new vertices)?
How would that be possible, and what would a formal proof look like?
There were similar questions but none that have this case(the graph is strictly directed, vertices cannot be added) as far as I saw.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

DAG nodes can be topologically sorted, which means that for each arc (a,b), node a is to the left of node b in the sort.

One way to do what you want is to first topologically sort the DAG. Say it has n nodes total. After the sort, a node at position i will have n-i-1 nodes after it. If the outdegree of the node at i is < n-i-1 for any i, then you can add an arc.

Now, if you are guaranteed that you have a DAG and want to know how many arcs you can add and still preserve the DAG attribute, but you don't need to identify them, you can do that much quicker. Notice that in a complete DAG (one with all possible arcs), after the topo sort the outdegrees will be [n-1, n-2, ..., 1, 0], and their sum will be n*(n+1)/2.

Find the count of arcs == sum of indegrees == sum of outdegrees. If this is less than n*(n+1)/2, the difference is the number of arcs you can add to the DAG while keeping it a DAG.

Comment: "Notice that in a complete DAG (one with all possible arcs), after the topo sort " This sentence is a bit unsettling - a complete directed graph is not acyclic; so a complete DAG would not be a complete directed graph; what does "all possible arcs" mean precisely? In particular, a DAG can be "maximal" in the sense that one cannot add any more arc without creating a cycle; but it cannot be "maximum". What you mean becomes clear when you say "the outdegrees will be [n-1, n-2, ..., 1, 0]", but I had never encountered the expression "complete DAG" before.

Comment: @Stef The nodes of every DAG can be topologically sorted. Every node can have an arc directed from it to every node farther along in the topological sort. A DAG that realizes this is complete. Every DAG can become a complete DAG by the addition of arcs.

Comment: @Stef If it helps, here is a link to a published paper that refers to complete DAGs. It has nothing to do with this problem; just sharing to illustrate that the term is in use. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0888613X9390006Y